# How to use List Iterable functions in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, iterable

I found iterable functions, but I am not sure how I can use.
For example, skip, take, map, forEach, fold and join

Could you give me examples how to use?

Comment: check https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables

Answer (score 2):

Yes, let's check the following sample code.

```
List<int> values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    
print(values.skip(5).toList());
//[6, 7, 8, 9]
    
print(values.skip(5).take(3).toList());
//[6, 7, 8]
    
values.skip(5).take(3).map((e) => e.toString()).forEach((element) {print(element);});
//6 7 8
    
String str = values.fold("initialValue",
        (previousValue, element) => previousValue + ", " + element.toString());    
print(str);
//initialValue, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    
str = values.join(", ");
print(str);
//1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

- skip(1) skips the first value, 1, in the values list literal.
- take(3) gets the next 3 values 2, 3, and 4 in the values list literal.
- map()   Returns a new lazy [Iterable] with elements that are created by calling `f` on each element of this `Iterable` in iteration order.
- fork()  Reduces a collection to a single value by iteratively combining each element of the collection with an existing value
- join()  Converts each element to a [String] and concatenates the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Avdienko and welcome to Stack Overflow. I will give you an example for a `.forEach` iterable function performed on a List.

```
List<int> listOfIntegers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

listOfIntegers.forEach((element) {
   print(element.toString() + " ");
});
```

This code will result in printing "1 2 3 4 5 " to the console.